# WordPress Hide Table Row Underline

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello ~  Looking for a way to remove the underlined rows in the WordPress table here:
    https://begnbark.com/wp/

Note: Borders are already set to '0'

```
<table style="height: 196px;" border="0" width="546">
```

Would appreciate illumination.  Many Thanks ~:~ Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `border-bottom: none` to `td` and `th` in your css or in your customizer custom css

```
table tbody th, table td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```